# Placing inputs/textarea on the right

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to place my inputs and `textarea` on the right of the screen and my labels on the left. To try and create a structured form. At this moment I have tried using float and position but they seem to conflict and give an ugly result. Is there a better way to do this? thanks in advance :)

edit: I can't use divs for this project

```css
form {
    border: 2px solid dimgrey;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);;
}

input, textarea {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
}

label {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="naam">Je naam:</label>
    <input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" size="25" maxlength="35" placeholder="Elon Musk">
    <label for="email">Je e-mailadress:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="25" maxlength="25" placeholder="JosDePutte@gmail.com">
    <label>Type vraag:
    <select name="Type Vraag">
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="ProductVraag">Vraag over een product</option>
        <option value="Andere">Andere</option>
    </select>
    </label>
    <label for="Vraag">Je vraag:
    <textarea id="Vraag" name="Vraag" maxlength="250"></textarea>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Verzend">
</form>
```

Comment: you need to change structure

Comment: Do you mean with fieldsets and such, I'm fairly new to html

Comment: check answer, is it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>Je naam:</td>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" size="25" maxlength="35" placeholder="Elon Musk">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Je e-mailadress:</td>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="25" maxlength="25" placeholder="JosDePutte@gmail.com">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type vraag:</td>
      <td align="right">
        <select name="Type Vraag">
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="ProductVraag">Vraag over een product</option>
          <option value="Andere">Andere</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Je vraag:</td>
      <td align="right">
        <textarea id="Vraag" name="Vraag" maxlength="250"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

it will work for you.

```css
.form-group{display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;margin-bottom:10px}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="naam">Je naam:</label>
    <input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" size="25" maxlength="35" placeholder="Elon Musk">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Je e-mailadress:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="25" maxlength="25" placeholder="JosDePutte@gmail.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Type vraag:</label>
    <select name="Type Vraag">
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="ProductVraag">Vraag over een product</option>
        <option value="Andere">Andere</option>
    </select>    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Vraag">Je vraag:</label>
    <textarea id="Vraag" name="Vraag" maxlength="250"></textarea>
    
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Verzend">
</form>
```

Comment: It's my bad for forgetting to mention that I'm not able to use divs for this. It's a school project

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Document</title>

<style>

  form {
      border: 2px solid dimgrey;

      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  input, textarea,select {
      margin-top: 10px;
      width: 70%;
      border: 1px solid #eee;
      padding: 0 10px
  }

  label {
      margin-top: 10px;
      width: 30%;
      flex-grow: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
  }

  input[type=submit] {
    margin-left: 30%;
    max-width: 150px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <form>
      <label for="naam">Je naam:</label>
      <input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" size="25" maxlength="35" placeholder="Elon Musk">
      <label for="email">Je e-mailadress:</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="25" maxlength="25" placeholder="JosDePutte@gmail.com">
      <label>Type vraag:</label>
      <select name="Type Vraag">
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="ProductVraag">Vraag over een product</option>
          <option value="Andere">Andere</option>
      </select>
      <label for="Vraag">Je vraag:</label>
      <textarea id="Vraag" name="Vraag" maxlength="250"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Verzend">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move inputs and textarea tag outside label tag and set width 50% and add some margin.

```css
form {
    border: 2px solid dimgrey;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);;
}

input, textarea, select {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
}

label {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="naam">Je naam:</label>
    <input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" size="25" maxlength="35" placeholder="Elon Musk">
    <label for="email">Je e-mailadress:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="25" maxlength="25" placeholder="JosDePutte@gmail.com">
    <label>Type vraag:
    </label>
     <select name="Type Vraag">
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="ProductVraag">Vraag over een product</option>
        <option value="Andere">Andere</option>
    </select>
    <label for="Vraag">Je vraag:
   
    </label>
     <textarea id="Vraag" name="Vraag" maxlength="250"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Verzend">
</form>
```